# How Can I Always Reset My Workplace Settings for Every Time I Quit VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What I want is to have all of my workplace preferences reset every time I quit VS Code. Right now, if I quit the application and opened the same folder I previously closed, VS Code still retains all pointer positions and all opened files. This maybe good for a lot of people, but for me, I just feel overwhelmed.

What I have tried:

- I tried to locate .vscode folder but it is non-existent in my project folder.
- "Clear Command History" doesn't work.
- "Clear Editor History" doesn't work.
- Following this link ---> https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42948 and deleting /home//.config/Code/Local Storage doesn't work.
- Following this link ---> https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42948 and running `window.localStorage.clear()` in Electron development console returns `undefined`.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings menu you can search for `window.restoreWindows` and change that to none. You can also change `workbench.editor.restoreViewState` to `false` which might also help.

Comment: Okay... the files aren't opening anymore. But, the cursors still persist.

Comment: Nevermind again, actually folder with .vscode folder inside still opens the files. What wonder is that some of my projects have this .vscode folder and some others don't.